# How to dynamically add radiobuttons and not lose view contents

Tags: android, radio-group

My layout looks like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:text="Please select the restaurant you want to rate: " />

        <RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/SelectRestaurant">

         </RadioGroup>
         <Button android:layout_width="100px"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:text="Rate it" 
         android:id="@+id/submitSelection"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I add radiobuttons to the radiogroup in java file, radiobuttons are overlapping on each other and submit button is gone. I guess radiobuttons are overriding other elements of view. How can I dynamically add these radio buttons without losing other elements.

Java code looks like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.submit_select);
        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.SelectRestaurant);
        for (String restaurant : restaurants) {
            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getBaseContext());
            radioButton.setText(restaurant);
            radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
        }
        radioGroup.invalidate();
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_SUBMIT_ID);
        rateItButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitSelection);
        rateItButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: "radiobuttons are overlapping on each other and submit button is gone" - it is a bit unclear, could you post a screenshot of it? I guess since you are not using `ScrollView` the button disapears because it gets pushed out of the visible part of the screen. However without the screenshot this is just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating Layout Parameters with WRAP_CONTENT for the width and height and then adding the layoutParams when you add the button to the group:

```
radiogroup.addView(newRadioButton, layoutParams);
```